# Http Get request: What's the difference when you access localserver and webserver?

Tags: http, sockets, client

I'm pretty new to socket programming and I'm writing a http client right now.

I'm a little confused for accessing a folder locally verse those on webserver. When I put a file into a folder locally, say my link is:

http://localhost:8000/1/example.html

I have to set my GET header with `path=/example.html`, `hostname=localhost/1` to make my client work, so the GET request is like:

```
GET /example.html HTTP/1.0
Host:localhost/1
```

However, from a webserver, like http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html, my hostname should be set to `info.cern.ch` instead of `info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW` and I shoud set `path=/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html.` The request looks like:

```
GET /hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.0
Host:info.cern.ch
```

I just wonder what's causing this difference? Is the directory in one url works differently than a local folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But: "localhost/1" is not a valid hostname - "localhost" is. The path in the URL should therefore be "/1/example.html". The web server can translate the path of the URL to whatever. It does not even need to be a real path on the filesystem, but can be an entry in the database etc.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Hi Steffen, that's where I'm confused, my http client works fine with the typical solution for hostname and path for a website, but when it comes to localhost, if I don't change the hostname and path like what I mentioned, my client cannot find the file I put in the folder,for example http://localhost:8000/1/example.html it'll return 404 to me, it can only find the file I put in the root, like http://localhost:8000/example.html

Comment: How the path gets mapped to a local file (or database entry or content is dynamically created ...) fully depends on the server. Nothing is known about your server and setup.

Comment: @MolecularCar What you have described is not how HTTP works, so if that is how your localhost server actually behaves then it is seriously broken. How the remote webserver behaves is the correct behavior. The ONLY difference there should be between a local server and a remote server is the IP address that the client connects to, nothing more. Everything about HTTP is agnostic to *where* the underlying socket is connected.